# Как рандомно сопоставить записи в таблице?

Tags: python, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли перенести данные из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2 следующим образом: по порядку user_id должен сохраниться в таблицу 2 в столбец user_id1; следующий по user_id должен сохраниться в столбец user_id2  и т.д.?

Я пытаюсь из исходной таблицы с данными пользователей сформировать таблицу с рандомным попарным сопоставлением user_id.
Буду рада любым советам!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *по порядку user_id должен сохраниться в таблицу 2 в столбец user_id1* По КАКОМУ порядку? *возможно ли перенести данные из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2* Да. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: Добрый день, порядок - случайный.

Comment: Посчитать номера записей со случайной сортировкой, а потом объединить по равенству `ROW_NUMBER() DIV 2`.